# Error compiling Mosquitto 1.4

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have tried to compile Mosquitto on both Arch and CentOS 7, but everytime I get the same error. I want to test the Websocket feature.

This is the procedure I am using for CentOS:

> yum group install "Development Tools"
>
> yum install cmake openssl-devel cmake
>
> yum install uuid-devel libxslt docbook5-style-xsl.noarch docbook-style-xsl.noarch
>
> git clone https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.git
>
> cd libwebsockets/
>
> mkdir build;cd build
>
> cmake ..
>
> make
>
> make install
>
> git clone https://git.eclipse.org/r/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto
>
> cd org.eclipse.mosquitto/
>
> git checkout origin/1.4
>
> vi config.mk
>
> Change "WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes"
>
> make

And this is where it dies on Arch and CentOS:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/install/org.eclipse.mosquitto/src'
cc -Wall -ggdb -O2  -I. -I.. -I../lib  -DVERSION="\"1.4\""   -DTIMESTAMP="\"2015-05-04 17:17:55+0200\"" -DWITH_BROKER -DWITH_TLS -DWITH_TLS_PSK -DWITH_UUID -DWITH_BRIDGE -DWITH_PERSISTENCE -DWITH_MEMORY_TRACKING -DWITH_SYS_TREE -DWITH_WEBSOCKETS -DWITH_EC -c mosquitto.c -o mosquitto.o

In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:25:0,
             from mosquitto.c:22:
/usr/include/features.h:148:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and  _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
 # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
mosquitto.c: In function ‘main’:
mosquitto.c:275:101: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
_mosquitto_log_printf(NULL, MOSQ_LOG_INFO, "mosquitto version %s (build date %s) starting", VERSION, TIMESTAMP);
 mosquitto.c:290:54: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
snprintf(buf, 1024, "mosquitto version %s", VERSION);
mosquitto.c:368:88: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
_mosquitto_log_printf(NULL, MOSQ_LOG_INFO, "mosquitto version %s terminating", VERSION);
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'mosquitto.o' failed
make[1]: *** [mosquitto.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/install/org.eclipse.mosquitto/src'
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'mosquitto' failed
make: *** [mosquitto] Error 2
```

If someone can please point out what I am doing wrong or missing ?

Comment: Does it do the same if you compile with a pristine source, i.e. without websockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hardillb says, the VERSION defines are the problem. If I add the line

```
#define VERSION
```

to mosquitto.c, then I can reproduce the error that you see, but also get a warning about redefining VERSION.

If I remove the definition of VERSION from config.mk, then I get an error about VERSION not being defined.

These both make sense.

What seems to be happening for you is that the compiler is ignoring the command line definition `-DVERSION="\"1.4.1\""` and replacing it with `-DVERSION=`, or isn't parsing the string properly. This doesn't make sense.

Other people have managed to compile on Arch, and the [CentOS7 repository](https://build.opensuse.org/project/repository_state/home:oojah:mqtt/CentOS_CentOS-7) has a binary version - but without websockets.

---

After some investigation, it appears as though there is a bug in recent libwebsockets code. [This changeset](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/commit/f1b125442be619c43bff45791a3f6fd5726099b5) introduces some changes that mean that libwebsockets is claiming the macro `VERSION` all for itself, which isn't very polite for a library. If you use a released version of libwebsockets you should not have any problem compiling.

Comment: Do you know where can I get a released version of libwebsockets from ?

Comment: I have found this one [https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/archive/v1.3-chrome37-firefox30.tar.gz](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/archive/v1.3-chrome37-firefox30.tar.gz).  Just busy reinstalling my ARCH VM

Comment: Yep, that would do - there is a list at https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/releases including the latest 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest have you tried building from the TGZ src bundle for Mosquitto 1.4.1 available here:

http://mosquitto.org/download/

The errors look to be something to do with expanding the passed in VERSION and TIMESTAMP values. It builds fine [with the exception of the docs] on Fedora 20 which shouldn't be that far from RHEL 7.0 (and from there to Centos 7).

Comment: Does the same on both Arch and CentOS.

Comment: I set WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=no and it compiles without any issues. I want/need Websockets, so where do I go from here ?

Comment: I tested the git and the tgz, on both if set WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=no they both compile....